# render MVC view with json data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a method that return json data to my mvc view, not sure why my view shows json data instead of what I have in success part. This is my Post method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("resetpassword")]
public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel resetPasswordViewModel)
{
   ...
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (resetPasswordViewModel.Password == resetPasswordViewModel.ConfirmPassword)
        {
            var user = Task.Run(() => Service.GetUserByEmailAsync(email)).Result;
            if (user != null)
            {
                userRequest.Id = user.FirstOrDefault().Id;
                userRequest.Password = resetPasswordViewModel.Password;
                userRequest.Token = token;
                await Service.UpdateUserAsync(userRequest);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { status = "error", message = "Please enter the same value again" });
        }
    }
    return Json(new { status = "success", message = "" });
}
```

This is my view that is modal:

```
@model Models.ResetPasswordViewModel

@if (Model != null)
{
    <div class="page resetPassword">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("resetpassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="modal" id="reset-password">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="close">X</span>
                    <div><input type="email" name="email" id="email" readonly value=@Model.Email /></div>
                    <div class="create-user-label">Password</div>
                    ....
```

and this is my ajax function:

```
function resetPassword() { 
    var postResult = null;
    var data = {
        Email: document.getElementById('email').value
    };
    var path = "/resetpassword";
    var errorMessage = document.getElementById('Message');

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "text/plain",
        url: path,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (result) {
            postResult = $.parseJSON(result);
            alert(postResult.data);
            if (result && result.message) {
                $('#reset-password').hide();
                $('#reset-thank-you').show();
            }
        },
        error: function () { alert("error"); }
    });
}
```

but instead of my view I only see json data in my screen like:

```
{"status":"success","message":""}
```

Comment: Not sure this is the problem but I would think you would want to 'await' GetUserByEmailAsync as well.

Comment: It suggests that your have a submit button that is triggering that function, and you have not cancelled the default submit (so your making a ajax call and a normal submit). What is the element that triggers that call? (and note, you also need to remove `contentType: "text/plain",`)

Comment: In addition, the method returns json, so delete `postResult = $.parseJSON(result);` (its already json)

Comment: As mentioned by Stephen, form submit is the cause of this behavior. You need to change type of button which is calling resetPassword to "button" instead of "submit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data will be automatically converted from JSON format into Javascript objects.

Presumably you just want to display the message in an alert:

```
  success: function (result) 
  {
      alert(result.data.message);
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your data is going through, looks like you have some mapping problems, you should try this.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "text/plain",
    url: path,
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result['status']);
        if (result['status']== 'success') {
            $('#reset-password').hide();
            $('#reset-thank-you').show();
        }
    },
    error: function () { alert("error"); }
});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with OP's issue

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.